# How to fork a child process in python by passing all its dependency

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I've a python file, say A.py which depends upon several other packages/folders/files let's call them B.py, C.py, D.py etc. and these are residing in some different location than A.py

A.py contents::

```
import B, C, D
//other codes
```

and I am calling A.py from another python script, let's call it 1.py

1.py contents:

```
child_process = subprocess.Popen("python A.py", shell=True)
```

And I run 1.py like this in command line:
python 1.py

my question is how to pass a series of dependencies, in this case, B.py, C.py, D.py to A.py in the child process to run it successfully.

I am using python 2.7

Comment: `python-3.x` _and_ `python-2.7`?

Comment: i am running in python 2.7

Answer (score 2):

You should correctly install `B`/`C`/`D` files in the python path.
Alternatively you can use the `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable:

```
child_process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'A.py'], env={'PYTHONPATH': '/path/to/the/directory'})
```

Where `/path/to/the/directory` is the path to the directory containing `B`, `C` and `D`.

Depending on what `A.py` does you may need to pass also some more of the environment. This can be achieved by either:

- setting the env variable in the parent process and let the child process inherit it:

  ```
  import os
  os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/path/...'
  Popen(['python', 'A.py'])   # by default it inherits parent env
  ```
- or copy the parent environment:

  ```
  new_env = dict(os.environ) # make a copy
  new_env['PYTHONPATH']  = '/path/...'
  Popen(['python', 'A.py', env=new_env)
  ```

---

**Note**: using `shell=True` is a security hazard. Also it is useless and less efficient. you should avoid it and pass the command line as a list of strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I will try this.. but what is the significance of shell=False/True.. in case of shell=False, where the child process runs..?

Comment: @Manoranjan It runs as a child of the python process. You do not need a shell to have child processes. By using `shell=True` you are only an useless layer in between. It is useful only if you actually using shell features. For example `Popen('cat some_file | grep "x*xx" | wc -l > num_linex.txt', shell=True)` in this case piping output using `|` and redirecting it to a file is a shell-feature. You could still re-implement it in python but is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @Manoranjan Unfortunately it is easy to introduce security problems using `shell=True`. For example if you have `Popen('cat %s' % filename)` and you obtain `filename` from the user the user could enter a file name like `; rm -fr /` which deleted all files from your computer. Moreover some attacks do not even require user input, for example `Popen('cat hello.txt')` is still vulnerable to shellshock: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_shock

Comment: I finally got the reason around shell=True/False.. but I've one more quest.. that is sometimes I am not able to terminate/kill the child process.. what could be reason..

    child_process.terminate() or kill()
    
either of this is not working immediately.. it takes some time to terminate or sometimes I have to issue two consecutive kill() commands.. still I find the process is in running status. it is not killed at all.. I guess this could be the case of defunct process.. what is this defunct one.. is this harmful.. this thing is weird for me.. could u plz give ur inputs on this.?

Comment: @Manoranjan It might be that your parent process is not waiting for the child process to finish, leaving a "zombie" process... Anyway I believe you should ask a different question about that. Specify which OS you are using (processes behaviour is OS specific, especially in "corner case" situations like termination etc) and provide a very simple example that replicates the situation.

Comment: yeah sure.. even I was thinking for posting a different question.. thanks Giacomo..